# C++ Add to the end of a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to add a line of code to the end of a lambda, similar to what the `+=` operator does to `std::string`. For instance:

```
std::function<void()> foo = []() {
    std::cout << "User defined code\n";
};

foo += [](){ std::cout << "I added this"; };
```

Desired output after calling `foo()`:

```
User defined code
I added this
```

Of course this does not actually work as written.

Is this possible, or is there another way to effectively accomplish the same thing? Perhaps copying the lambda to another std::function then pass by value to a new lambda or something?

Edit:

I'm working with a class with a `std::function` member (`foo`) initialized with a lambda. Its member functions call it directly (with `foo()`) and I need to make it so that every time `foo` is called, an additional function is called as well. However this can be done would be great, as long as `foo` can still be called with `foo();`.

Comment: Lambdas don't work this way. You simply have to write a new lambda that calls the first one.

Comment: So to sum up, the OP is looking for something like `event` in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the type of the member, something like this might do it:

```
class Functions
{
public:
    using Function = std::function<void()>;

    Functions() = default;
    template<typename Fn>
    Functions(Fn f) { functions.push_back(f); }

    Functions& operator+=(Function f)
    {
        functions.push_back(f);
        return *this;
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        for (auto& f: functions)
        {
            f();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Function> functions;
};

Functions foo = []() { cout << "Hello"; }
foo += []() { cout << ", world!"; };
foo();
```

Comment: This works, thank you! But what 's the reasoning behind templating `Functions(Fn f)` instead of using `Functions(Function f)`?

Comment: @TheJared802 To be honest, it's just because it didn't compile for me otherwise – I'm not sure why – and I didn't want to post uncompilable code.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is the closest I could come up with for your problem at hand:

```
class Lambdas
{
    vector<function<void()>> lambdas;
public:
    Lambdas(function<void()> lamb) 
    { 
       lambdas.push_back(lamb); 
    }

    Lambdas& operator+=(function<void()> lamb)
    {
        lambdas.push_back(lamb);
        return *this;
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<lambdas.size(); i++)
        {
            lambdas[i]();
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. While this is useful (and not something I would have though of), I'm working with another class that calls a member `std::function` object (foo) directly. `foo` is filled with a lambda when the class is initialized, and for certain instances of the class I need an additional action (the added part) to run every time foo is called. So calling foo1(foo) isn't an option, since that would mean editing the other class.